# How to set the size of pic/video rendered by manim?

Tags: python, manim

The default size of picture or video rendered by `manim` is 1920*1080. But I want to resize it to for example 2000 * 2000, and I don't know how to modify it.

I browsed the doc of manim, but I haven't find any useful ways.

Can you help me with it?

[image]

---

I tried to modify `frame_height`,`frame_width`,`frame_size`,but nothing happend.
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim._config.utils.ManimConfig.html#manim._config.utils.ManimConfig.frame_height

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the `-r`, and set e.g. -r 2000,2000.

Here I wrote a whole tutorial how to change the pixel size:
https://flyingframes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ch5.html
[image]

Comment: I tried that like this: "manim -r 3664,1980 test.py TrigCircle". It renders alright but nothing is shown. The output is "Rendered TrigCircle Played 0 animations". And if I use "manim  test.py TrigCircle -p -r 3664,1980" instead, the animation is played but with a black frame around. I can't seem to have the resolution and the video frame to be exactly my custom resolution.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- Do not use `-q` or `--quality` parameter, as those default to the standard manim's aspect ratio.
- Set the desired pixel size with e.g. `pixel_width` and `pixel_height`.
- Set either `frame_width` or `frame_height` to the number of desired logical units. No need to set the other one, it is automatically set for you.
- If you want to render your video at other "qualities" you'll just have to adjust the pixel width/height.

E.g. the following `manim.cfg` does mainp's default "low quality" but in portrait orientation:

```
[CLI]
pixel_width = 450
pixel_height = 800
frame_width = 8
```